# Is svelte docs about writable stores wrong or is it VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, svelte, sveltekit

If I do exactly as the docs for Svelte regarding writable stores https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores I get a warning in VSCode:

```
Module '"./stores.js"' has no exported member 'count'.
```

It returns an object not a variable.

This is my code:

```
//stores.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export const count = writable(0);

//index.svelte
<script>
  import { count } from './stores.js';
  console.log(count);
</script>
```

[image]

Why is that? Is the docs or VSCode wrong?

Comment: that's an issue with vscode

Comment: that is very odd, definitely an issue with VS Code. might fix it, might not but have all store files in src/lib/stores.js or even further src/lib/stores/[storeName].js and import into svelte files using '$lib' alias